# How to sign out from Window Authentication in Browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I want to sign out windows authentication from browser (ASP.NET application). Actually I want to ask for authentication every time the user open the site. But it is asked only once.

> How to end the Windows Authentication session from browser?

Comment: SharePoint does it by asking the user to close the browser after logging-out.

Comment: Try reading this article http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=825.. As far as I can tell, you can tell IE to ask for the user's credentials.